# Wrong date from components

Tags: ios, swift, date, calendar, nsdatecomponents

So this is interesting:

```
po Calendar.default.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2022, month: 1, hour: 16, minute: 1, second: 1, weekday: 1, weekOfMonth: 1))
▿ Optional<Date>
  ▿ some : 2021-12-26 23:01:01 +0000
    - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 662252461.0
```

I'm expecting January 1st 2022, but I'm getting December 26th 2021? Why is it doing this? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the date components you are providing are contradictory.  You have weekDay 1 (which will probably be a Sunday or Monday, depending on your locale) but the 1 jan 2022 is a Saturday.

(you also used `Calendar.default` when I think you meant `Calendar.current`?)

If you take out the `weekDay` term you will get the correct answer:

```
Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: 2022, month: 1, hour: 16, minute: 1, second: 1, weekOfMonth: 1))

// "Jan 1, 2022 at 4:01 PM"
```

You could also remove the `weekOfMonth` term as it is superfluous when you are specifying the actual date.

Comment: I removed weekOfMonth and it worked. Thanks! Calendar.default exists in an extension I created, which is usually autoUpdatingCurrent.

Comment: @xytor no problem.  It would appreciated if you could accept the answer if you are happy with it.

Comment: I don't see a button to do that.